Faces glitch when texture paint
When I texture paint I found some faces that changed color. It's like related faces-what I paint on one face duplicated on another. I already cut my model with seams for better grid. But I have overlapping because of related points.
On this screenshot you can see that if I select one point on my mesh its several points on UV. How to fix it?

I still can't realised how to make a one point from this several points in UV. My steps: Unwrap by smart uv project, check overlapping and fix them. but when I try to move them on UV map 3 or 4 point move together. What do I do wrong?

this is my file


"But I have overlapping because of related points. " I wonder what that means. Anyway, just make a UV map that does not have overlapping UVs - it's as simple as that. UV Islands should have some gaps between them as well.

Hello, it's not clear what is your problem, if you mean that the faces are overlapping, it won't be good for your painting, you need to make sure that it's not the case, by the way if the goal is to paint your object in the 3D view, you don't have to use seams, you can simply unwrap with a Smart UV Project.

Oh all right thanks I'll change it. Sorry for stupidity

sorry I still can't get it. I edit my question and added a blend file

Your UV islands are too close to each other, the color bleeds onto the adacent island, to fix that unwrap again and in the Operator Box increase the Island Margin to something like  0.001:


No, it doesn't work. With Island Margin 0.001 or 0.03 points still related somehow

Thank you very much for help. I fixed it. It was this "UV Sync Selection" bottom

what do you mean, not sure how the the Sync button fixed your problem?
